# R - need a function to form groups for evaluation

Tags: r, statistics, evaluation, group

R - Statistics
Hello everyone,
I have used different items in my questionnaire to ask if the person belongs to a certain group or not ( for a categorical variable with 2 expressions).
Now I wanted to divide the groups in R, however I can't find a function that helps me.
In my questionnaire, you could choose 1 or 2 (sometimes more than one) answer choices, but they are categorical.
I wanted to divide one group if they have selected 1 everywhere in the questionnaire and the other if they have selected 1 or the other options.
I hope I could explain this understandably, thank you in advance :).

Tried to look up in different books and websites, but could not find anything.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. You can make it easier for others to help if you provide sample input data, an example of your desired output and which R functions / packages you've already researched for your purpose, and why/how they did not return the expected result. This guidance might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The easiest way to provide a reproducible example in R is often `dput()`. If you have an R object, you can use `dput()` to make a copy/pasteable version of it. For example `dput(my_data[1:5, 2:4])` will make a copy/pasteable version of the first 5 rows and columns 2:4 of `my_data`. If you could share a small example that illustrates the problem along with the expected result, that makes it possible to help you much better. Try to share just enough data to illustrate the problem, yet not too little to over-simplify.